# SQLite Android index out of bounds issue

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, adk

I'm trying to add a post in an SQLite Database and retrieving it right afterwards. 
I seem to be appending the post correctly but when it comes to retrieving I'm getting this error.

```
05-23 00:26:03.088: E/AndroidRuntime(30715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 00:26:03.088: E/AndroidRuntime(30715): Process: com.deparesmatteo.www, PID: 30715
05-23 00:26:03.088: E/AndroidRuntime(30715): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:            Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
05-23 00:26:03.088: E/AndroidRuntime(30715):    at     android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
05-23 00:26:03.088: E/AndroidRuntime(30715):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
```

These are the methods i'm using:

```
public static PostEntity createPost(final PostEntity entity)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteOpenHelper._TITLE, entity.getPostTitle());
    values.put(MySQLiteOpenHelper._DESCRIPTION, entity.getPostDesc());
    values.put(MySQLiteOpenHelper._CATEGORY, entity.getPostCategory());
    values.put(MySQLiteOpenHelper._IMAGEURL, entity.getPostImageURL());
    long postId=database.insert(MySQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Cursor cursor =database.query(MySQLiteOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, ALL_COLUMNS, MySQLiteOpenHelper._ID+" = '"+(postId)+"'", null, null, null, null);
    return getEntityFromCursor(cursor);
}
private static PostEntity getEntityFromCursor(final Cursor cursor)
{
    PostEntity entity = new PostEntity(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
    return entity;
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT

---

```
private final static String[] ALL_COLUMNS = {MySQLiteOpenHelper._ID.toString(),   MySQLiteOpenHelper._TITLE, MySQLiteOpenHelper._DESCRIPTION, MySQLiteOpenHelper._CATEGORY,  MySQLiteOpenHelper._IMAGEURL};
```

these are the all column declarations

MySQLiteOpenHelper declarations

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "post";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="posts.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String _TITLE = "title";
public static final String _DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String _CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String _IMAGEURL = "image";


private static final String DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
                                        "(" + _ID + " integer primary key, " +
                                        _TITLE + " text not null, "
                                        + _DESCRIPTION + " text not null, "
                                        + _CATEGORY + " text not null, "
                                        + _IMAGEURL + " text not null "+");";
```

Comment: Where's your DDL and important bits, such as `ALL_COLUMNS`...?

Comment: private final static String[] ALL_COLUMNS = {MySQLiteOpenHelper._ID.toString(), MySQLiteOpenHelper._TITLE, MySQLiteOpenHelper._DESCRIPTION, MySQLiteOpenHelper._CATEGORY, MySQLiteOpenHelper._IMAGEURL};  I omitted them from the post because they seem to be working in other contexts. All the declarations are there

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit your question instead. Don't forget to provide your DDL, as well as the contracts in MySQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I just re-read, and it turns out, you just forgot to walk the cursor -- you need to `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you read values from it. Might be a good idea at that time to check that the cursor isn't null, and that it even contains data.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `.toString()` on `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to access the cursor correctly. Change your `getEntityFromCursor()` to:

```
private static PostEntity getEntityFromCursor(final Cursor cursor) {
    PostEntity entity = null;
    if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        entity = new PostEntity( cursor.getInt(0),
                                 cursor.getString(1),
                                 cursor.getString(2),
                                 cursor.getString(3),
                                 cursor.getString(4) );
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Checking the cursor for `null` is not necessary.